# gcutil moveinstances failing due to "KeyError: u'CPUS'"

Tags: python, gcutil

I am trying to move my micro-sized Compute Engine from us-central2-a to us-central1-a, since Google will be doing maintenance on the first zone in a week. I am running gcutil-1.9.0 on my Windows machine, via Cygwin.

I ran the exact command they suggested:

```
gcutil moveinstances --replace_deprecated --source_zone=us-central2-a --destination_zone=us-central1-a ".*" --project=careful-isotope-239
```

and got the following result:

```
Checking destination zone...
Retrieving instances in us-central2-a matching: .*...
Checking disk preconditions...
Checking quotas...
KeyError: u'CPUS'
```

So, this is evidently a Python error, but I have no idea how to proceed. Anybody have ideas?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

You should use --service_version=v1beta15 flag, they've broken the API for getzone (moveinstances is tryind to verify CPUS quota).